# Problema Angular ui.router al poner <ui-view></ui-view> en index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui.router

Buenos días.

Estoy haciendo una web con NodeJs y AngularJs usando bower para las librerias, gulp para tareas, uso ui.router para hacer las rutas y tengo en index.html una etiqueta div ui-view que trato de hacerla dinamica para cambiar el contenido. Pero me salen errores de "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once." y "Error: transition superseded", he buscado ya en google e intentado soluciones que he visto, pero a mi no me funcionan.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Os dejo mis archivos:
- Ficheros [index.js + bower.json + package.json](http://pastebin.com/8ZcKzB76)
- Ficheros [app.js + gulpfile.js + index.html](http://pastebin.com/yAMiyvtv)

Como no puedo poner otro link, pongo los errores mostrados así:

```html
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.  app.min.js:13:11919
Error: transition superseded
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14124
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}  vendor.min.js:10:13220
Error: transition prevented
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14190
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}  vendor.min.js:10:13220
Error: transition aborted
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14253
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}  vendor.min.js:10:13220
Error: transition failed
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14313
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled reWARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.  app.min.js:13:11919
Error: transition superseded
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14124
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}  vendor.min.js:10:13220
Error: transition prevented
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14190
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}  vendor.min.js:10:13220
Error: transition aborted
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14253
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}  vendor.min.js:10:13220
Error: transition failed
$get@http://localhost:5000/scripts/app.min.js:14:14313
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
injectionArgs@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21693
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22050
registerDirective/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2391
forEach@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:18505
registerDirective/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:2312
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
enforceReturnValue/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:18779
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:23357
getService@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:21176
addDirective@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:29640
collectDirectives@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:12672
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9583
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compileNodes@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:9988
compile@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:8:6527
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30821
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6423
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:11:6769
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30762
invoke@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:7:22205
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:30653
bootstrap@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:31135
angularInit@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:6:29882
@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:16:3177
resolve/</mightThrow@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1320
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:5000/scripts/vendor.min.js:3:1964
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}jection: {}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Podrías subir tu archivo index.html

Comment: [Edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/41483/edit) tu pregunta y sube los ficheros `index.html`, `gulpfile.js` y `app.js`. Así mismo, sube una imagen con los errores mostrados por consola o copia los mismos y pégalos en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que como dice en inglés, la librería del AngularJS "está siendo cargada más de una vez"

Es posible que tu primer archivo haga include desde el tag < Script > y posteriormente algún otro incluya a la misma librería angularjs de nuevo, lo que implica que se dé ese error en el arranque

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once

Comment: Pero aún con ese error, si en index.html quito la etiqueta ui-view, los demás errores se van, que está mal con ui-router para provocar esos fallos y que no cambie el contenido de ui-router?

Comment: No me deja editar el comentario anterior...Viendo mi index.html desde el navegador, los script que se inyectan son app.min.js y vendor.min.js, que se definen en el fichero gulpfile.js, no se desde donde más puede cargar angular, ni que ocasiona los errores de ui.router

Comment: ¿Lograste resolver? Perdona no leí hasta ahora la pregunta

Comment: Hola. No he tenido mucho tiempo estos días, pero he estado mirando y aún no he sabido donde esta el problema, como has dicho más arriba se cargará en otro lado, sobre lo del ui-view, sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Hola, si tengo una pista que quizas te pueda servir, no estoy seguro cien por ciento, pero me pasó algo similar con uiRouter estos dias

Comment: ...
Estaba haciendo seteo dinámico de uiroutes, y en la asignación, de el state, se producia un bucle sin fin en el caso de hace el 
$state.go('algunState') desde un controlador, pués al hacer el cambio de estado, la página parece volver a cargarse, y volver a declarar al controlador, entonces se iba por un bucle recursivo descontrolado de anidamiento

Quizá no te pasó a tí pero cuando me dió esa traza tan iterativa me acorde tu incidente. buen día

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero yo no tengo $state.go, uso simplemente $state('loquesea'), en todo caso, no parece que la pagina se recargue constantemente, otras cosas parecen funcionar bien.